Installing kernel header files on buildroot filesystem
I am running LTS 6.6.35 linux kernel on qemu-aarch64, with buildroot as rootfs. The toolchain used is arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.
Firstly, I did not understand why this toolchain comes with 4.20.x headers. I chose 6.6.x headers under Toolchain > External toolchain kernel headers series, but buildroot found headers to be 4.20.x. Why toolchai, despite being latest, is getting shipped with such old headers?
In buildroot rootfs, I want linux kernel headers corresponding to my kernel 6.6.35 because when I run certain programs (e.g. bpftrace or bcc tools), they complaint about missing headers.
# ./bitehist.py
In file included from <built-in>:2:
In file included from /virtual/include/bcc/bpf.h:12:
In file included from include/linux/types.h:6:
In file included from include/uapi/linux/types.h:14:
In file included from include/linux/posix_types.h:5:
In file included from include/linux/stddef.h:5:
In file included from include/uapi/linux/stddef.h:5:
include/linux/compiler_types.h:167:10: fatal error: 'asm/compiler.h' file not found
#include <asm/compiler.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//./bitehist.py", line 21, in <module>
    b = BPF(text="""
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 479, in __init__
Exception: Failed to compile BPF module <text>

and this is how bpftrace is complaining.
# bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:raw_syscalls:sys_enter { @[comm] = count(); }'
fatal error: '/lib/modules/6.6.35-ga78e9d5d3e33-dirty/build/include/linux/kconfig.h' file not found
#

I was able to do install some headers using make headers_install but it seems it still doesn't copy all the required headers. Installing via a package manager is not an option. What should I do? What is the right approach?

dirty means that you have modified kernel without properly patching it, i.e. in place. For the start I would make sure you have no such word in the kernel version.

Second part is that Buildroot has its own toolchain. Why do you use external one (which is obviously build against Linux kernel v4.20) instead?

Please correct me. My target kernel version is 6.6. This means all the binaries and tools should be compiled against 6.6 kernel headers. There is no point in using a toolchain that uses 4.20 kernel headers.

Yes, so why do you use that toolchain instead of the one provided by Buildroot?

Because the kernel image is built outside (not within buildroot). Its more flexible to just toss in any kernel image and re-use the buildroot rootfs. So I thought its a wise idea to use an external toolchain that can be used to build both the kernel and the buildroot rootfs

We are building our disk images using external (to Buildroot) kernels on everyday basis, so I don't see that part is anyhow relevant. What you need is once to build your toolchain in Buildroot and then build kernels using that toolchain. In case you are interested in our scripts, they are published on GitHub: https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot/tree/intel/board/intel/common.
